# C++ Disabling right mouse button event for a specific time when pressed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible to use something with GetKeyState and VK_RBUTTON code to make it delayed or even disable it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use `GetKeyState()` for that.

However, you can use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) instead to create a low-level mouse hook that delays/discards `WM_RBUTTON...` messages as needed.